# What is a peccato word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

This puzzle is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what%20is%20a%22%20word%20is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463/jlee) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What%20is%20%22%20%22Word%22%20-missing%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) puzzles.

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a **peccato** word.
Here is a list of peccato and not-peccato words:

| PECCATO | NOT PECCATO |
| --- | --- |
| moon | star |
| ceil | floor |
| agile | gawk |
| acid | basic |
| dig | pig |
| you | they |
| me | them |
| him | your |
| sport | hobby |
| clone | alien |

And CSV version:

```
PECCATO;NOT PECCATO
moon;star
ceil;floor
agile;gawk
acid;basic
dig;pig
you;they
me;them
him;your
sport;hobby
clone;alien
```

**QUESTION:** What is the rule to tell whether a word is a **peccato** word or not?

Hint 1

> it depends on the spelling of the words, not on the meanings

Hint 2

> It is somehow related to the pronunciation of the word "peccato", not to its meaning.

Hint 3

> Write down the alphabet. You should easily be able to find a **necessary** condition for a word to be a peccato word.

Hint 4 (strong hint)

> the rule is related to the letter O.

Comment: I tabelized it for you.

Comment: Thank you @jdrupal. As usual, I wanted to keep a table version for humans and a CSV version in case someone wants to analize it automatically.

Comment: Sorry, included the CSV version in my edit :)

Comment: No problem, I don't have my laptop right now otherwise I would have done the table myself.

Comment: Actually I did it on my phone, take a look at this website, https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Comment: This one is hard man. Do you have a hint?

Comment: I've added two hints

Comment: I've added one more hint

Comment: Oh I have no clue, I’m probably to dumb to solve this one :)

Comment: Some of this seems arbitrary. "Somehow related to the pronunciation of peccato" - is it? or isn't it? Is it how someone from Italy would pronounce it or America? Or somewhere else entirely?

Comment: By an English speaker. The rule is not arbitrary at all. I added the last hint

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The title is a hint:

> **PECCATO** is pronounced similarly to "{peek/peak}-at-O".  Which, leads the puzzle solver to focus on the letter 'O'. <sub>Full credit for this piece goes to Nahmid in the comments.</sub>

I believe a word is a Peccato word when:

> A word contains only letters from A-O **or** only letters from O-Z.  The letters must flow either A->Z or Z->A, only flipping the direction *once* (the ***peak*** letter).  The *peak* letter must appear be in the direction of 'O'.  The letter 'O' is not required for a word to be a Peccato word.

A word is Not Peccato word when:

> The word contains any letter before O **and** after O. Or when the letters do not flow in one direction, only changing at the *peak letter.

Proof:

> Peccato words should be either completely green (A-O) or completely blue (O-Z).  'O' is a wild-card letter and can be seen as either green or blue.
>  [image: Peccato Words Explained]
>  Also, follow the flow of each letter in a Peccato word.  The direction only changes once, at the *peak* letter.
>  [image: Flow explanation]

Comment: I believe the title is meant to be interpreted as rot13("crrx ng B"), which clues in this answer.

Comment: @Nahmid Thanks. I believe you are right!  I've edited my answer to add this interpretation.

Comment: Actually the rule is a bit more complicated. Look at the word "your" that I included among the not-peccato words. You need to look for the peak harder!

Comment: @kyle among your words only one, ale and soot are peccato words. Clone is also a peccato word, but it was included in my own list too

Comment: Ahhh. Not sure how I missed 'your'.  Does rot13("gur N-B be B-M svg va ng nyy?  Be nz V pbzcyrgryl bss onfr?")

Comment: I guess your answer is good, it's just not the whole picture. I think you should look closer at the last sentence of melfnt's first comment above. (The examples are all quite short. I guess that "chinook" and "belonged" are p-words, but that "feedback" and "oddball" aren't.)

Comment: @MOehm I see a pattern in the direction that Peccato letters flow.  In a P-word, the letters seem to flow either A->Z or Z->A, only flipping the direction when an 'O' is the letter (the **PEAK**).  However, that isn't the case with 'ale', and if 'ale' is a P-word this assumption is wrong.

Comment: This rule doesn't work with 'agile' either.

Comment: If what I think is right, your approach is good, but rot13(gur crnx vf abg arprffnevyl ng na b, vg whfg cbvagf gbjneqf na b). I think that is reasonable and it works for the given words, but it makes (already weak, imo) "peccato" a bit of a misnomer.

Comment: That is the rule I had in mind when I created the puzzle, congratulations! I don't understand why you said that it doesn't work for "agile": the rule works, just rot13 (Ntvyr qbrf abg pbagnva gur yrggre b)

Comment: I meant rot13 (Gur crnx vf nyjnlf gur yrggre B rira vs gur vg qbrf abg nccrne va gur jbeq)

Comment: @melfnt Gotcha!  Well I updated my answer.  Let me know if I missed anything.

Comment: Accepted :) happy new year